# Input type text border shows on click in chrome

Tags: html, css

**Hi friends I have trouble in input text. When i clicked in input box it shows blue border of input box. This problem is in only chrome browser. In Firefox this is not showing. what to do for this?**

```
<form id="search" name="search" method="post" action="index.php?act=srch">
 <input type="text" name="search" class="search-input" id="searchid" value="" autocomplete="off"  /><input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit-search" />
</form>

.search-input{
    border:none;
    background:none;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:17px;
    color:#4f4f4f;
    float:left;
    width:87%;
}
```

Comment: use `-webkit-border:none;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy following code Hope this may help you:

```
 input:focus
  {
     outline: none;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this.

```
.search-input{
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    background:none;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:17px;
    color:#4f4f4f;
    float:left;
    width:87%;
}
```

Comment: This is not working Amit....

Comment: check now it will work